# How to Pass tk.StringVar Variables and Insert Them into sqlite Database Table?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

In my main.py file in the method 'add_database_entry()' I'm passing 3 values

- self.name.get()
- self.phone_number.get()
- self.relationship.get()
  to the Database.py method 'add_entry()' method.
  However, my table contacts doesn't have any rows being added.
  Why is this? What am I doing wrong?
  Thank you.

main.py File

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
import database as connection


class AddressBook(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.title("John's Phone Address Book")
    self.resizable(True,True)
    self.geometry('400x400')
    self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

    # Create SQLite3 Database & DB File
    connection.create_table()

    # Create Container Frame
    container = ttk.Frame(self)
    container.grid()

    # Create Entry Frame
    entry_frame = Entry(container)
    entry_frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='W')

# Entry Frame Class
class Entry(ttk.Frame):
  def __init__(self,parent):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.name = tk.StringVar()
    self.phone_number = tk.StringVar()
    self.relationship = tk.StringVar()

    # Label Widgets
    name_label = ttk.Label(self,text='Name: ')
    phone_label = ttk.Label(self,text='Phone: ')
    relationship_label = ttk.Label(self,text='Relationship: ')

    name_label.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='W')
    phone_label.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='W')
    relationship_label.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky='W')

    # Entry Widgets
    self.name_entry = ttk.Entry(self,textvariable=self.name)
    self.phone_number_entry = ttk.Entry(self,textvariable=self.phone_number)
    self.relationship_entry = ttk.Entry(self,textvariable=self.relationship)

    self.name_entry.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='W')
    self.phone_number_entry.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='W')
    self.relationship_entry.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky='W')

    # Button Widgets
    clear_button = ttk.Button(self,text='Clear',command=self.clear_entry_fields)
    add_button = ttk.Button(self,text='Add',command=self.add_database_entry)

    clear_button.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')
    add_button.grid(row=3,column=1,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')

  # Clear Entry Fields
  def clear_entry_fields(self):
    self.name_entry.delete(0,'end')
    self.phone_number_entry.delete(0,'end')
    self.relationship_entry.delete(0,'end')

  def add_database_entry(self):
    print(self.name.get(),self.phone_number.get(),self.relationship.get())
    connection.add_entry(self.name.get(),self.phone_number.get(),self.relationship.get())
    self.clear_entry_fields()
```

Database.py File

```
import sqlite3

CREATE_TABLE_QUERY = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts(name TEXT,phone_number TEXT, relationship TEXT);'

INSERT_ENTRY_QUERY = "INSERT INTO contacts(name,phone_number,relationship) VALUES(?,?,?);"

# Create the Database & SQLite3 Database File
connection = sqlite3.connect('address_book.db')
# by default the connection grabs columns and stores them in a tuple which can be stored in the cursor
# you can change connection to grab columns and store them as a dictionary in the cursor.
connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

def create_table():
  connection.execute(CREATE_TABLE_QUERY)

def add_entry(name,phone_number,relationship):
  connection.execute(INSERT_ENTRY_QUERY,(name,phone_number,relationship))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call "commit" after executing an updating query:

```
def create_table():
  connection.execute(CREATE_TABLE_QUERY)
  connection.commit()

def add_entry(name,phone_number,relationship):
  connection.execute(INSERT_ENTRY_QUERY,(name,phone_number,relationship)) 
  connection.commit()
```